# How to decrease touch sensivity (Accidental taps)

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, touchscreen, system

When I try to scroll a list of elements, the system interprets it as a "tap" many times (but not always).

It is very annoying. To clarify, for example it happens when I make a search inside an app. I want to view all the results but when I try to move down so I can see the lower items, I accidentally select one of the items of the list and then when I go back to the list, it is again on the begining. When there is a lot of results I waste a lot of time to reach the end.

I'm using ResurrectionRemix (based on CyanogenMod 13) on Oneplus 3. It tried to do a full wipe and install latest version and it continues happening. I looks the same problem occuts on TWRP.

I drop my phone 1-2 month ago and my screen got cracked, but I didnt notice this problem until several days ago. May it be related to this problem?

Comment: *settings > Language and Input >  pointer speed* - decrease the slider to make the touch screen less sensitive . See if this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a hardware failure. Replacing my screen panel did the trick.